# What are those weird circle red icons at the top right in Ubuntu Mate Desktop?

Tags: server, mate

I recently managed to get VNC working on a Ubuntu Server on which I installed the Mate desktop. For some reason, those icons recently started showing up. They weren't there previously and right clicking on them doesn't do anything. Anyone has a clue?

[image]

Comment: They look like they're part of the VNC UI.